# Is it possible to use Vue components in .vue formats vs commonJS formats interchangeably?

Tags: javascript, components, commonjs, vue-component, vue.js

This is commonJS format

```
Vue.Component('custom-component',{
       template : '<p>Some template</p>',
       data : {}
       methods : {}
});
```

This is .vue format

```
<template>
    <p>Some template</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
           return {};
        },
        methods : {}            
    }

</script>
<style>
</style>
```

My question is, can you have a project with some components written in commonJS format and some components written in .vue format? If so, how do you import one kind of component in the other?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you **can.**

.vue files will be packed into common js and common js format will be left as is by webpack.